# AWK for sorting a field based on same multiple fields

Tags: awk

I have a file like below:

```
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 1.025 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
```

I want to print the row which has highest value in 6th field, while all other fields are unique.

Desired output:

```
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
```

Is there a smart way of doing this in awk?

Answer (score 1):

The sensible way would be to use sort+awk:

```
$ sort -k6,6nr file | awk '!seen[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7]++'
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
```

but if you want to just use awk you could do:

```
$ awk '
    { orig=$0; $6=""; key=$0; $0=orig }
    NR==FNR{ if ( !(key in max) || $6 > max[key] ) { max[key]=$6; nr[key]=NR } next }
    nr[key]==FNR
' file file
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain the your first answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want the fields to be inorder on the desired output,

```
awk '{if(uniqueSet[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$7] < $6) { uniqueSet[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$7] = $6} }END{for(i in uniqueSet){print i" "uniqueSet[i]} }' <input_file_name>
```

would give,

```
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L SETUP 0.867568
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L HOLD 0.850877
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L HOLD 0.85125
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L SETUP 2.3
```

if you want to persist the order of the fields,

```
awk '{if(uniqueSet[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$7] < $6) { uniqueSet[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$7] = $6} }END{for(i in uniqueSet){ split(i, ar, " "); print ar[1]" "ar[2]" "ar[3]" "ar[4]" "ar[5]" "uniqueSet[i]" "ar[6]} }' <input_file_name>
```

would give,

```
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
```

Comment: awesome :)  Would you mind giving an explanation to this also?

Comment: iterating on each row the script will put the contents of the rows into a map with the key being the fields of the row that need to be grouped on (in this case all the fields except the field no 6). And the value for that key is the max value of the field no 6 out of the rows that falls into that group. Once the iteration finished it just prints the `[ key value]` pair of the map

Comment: please note that this will only work when the values that are being compared are all positive

Comment: I believe this works based on associative array concept. Also any clue how this can be made on negative numbers also?

Comment: You could make it negative value friendly with adding the test for empty `uniqueSet`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk:

```
$ gawk ' {
    t=$6                                 # put $6 to temp
    $6="MARK"                            # replace it with a marker, use $0 as key
    if($0 in v==0 || t>v[$0]) {          # if $0 not in value hash or t>previous value
        a[$0]=NR                         # in a goes the record number for ordering
        v[$0]=t
    }
}
END {                                    # in the end
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc" # traverse a in growing order of NRs stored
    for(i in a) {
        sub(/MARK/,v[i],i)               # replace mark with value
        print i                          # and output
    }
}' file
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
```

Answer (score 0):

Short alternative with GNU **`datamash`** + **`cut`** tools:

```
datamash -Wf -g1,2,3,4,5,7 max 6 <file | cut -f1-7 --output-delimiter=' '
```

The output:

```
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.867568 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 2.3 SETUP
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] HIGH H2L 0.85125 HOLD
scale_check BANK0_F2_WRDAT_P0[0] MCLK[0] LOW H2L 0.850877 HOLD
```